# How can I replace consecutive whitespace with a single space from the whole string

Tags: elixir

I have a string with 2,3 or more spaces between non-space characters

```
string = "a  b c   d"
```

What can I do to make it like that:

```
output_string == "a b c d"
```

Comment: You probably want to change the title of your question.  You're not removing _trailing_ whitespace.  You're removing whitespace _within_ the string.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest way would be using Regular Expressions:

```
iex(1)> string = "a  b c   d"
"a  b c   d"
iex(2)> String.replace(string, ~r/ +/, " ") # replace only consecutive space characters
"a b c d"
iex(3)> String.replace(string, ~r/\s+/, " ") # replace any consecutive whitespace
"a b c d"
```

Comment: I started to wrote the answer, but you were first :)

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, you don't even need the regex:

```
iex(3)> "a b c    d" |> String.split |> Enum.join(" ")
#=>"a b c d"
```

Also just from my very little bit of smoke testing, it looks like this will work with any whitespace separators (i. e. it works on spaces and tabs as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be to `String#split` and `Enum#join`:

```
iex(1)> "a  b c   d" |> String.split(~r{\s+}) |> Enum.join(" ")
#⇒ "a b c d"
```

Comment: Similarly to `String.split("a  b c   d", ~r{\s+})` you can use the `:trim` option in String.split/3 like so: `String.split("a  b c   d", " ", trim: true)`

Comment: @Mallory-Erik `:trim` option [removes empty strings from the result](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/String.html#split/3). I used a regex for the sake of generality (when the delimiter is not a space.) Here plain old good `String.split/1` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Regex.replace(~r/\s+/, "a  b c   d", " ")